# Why is my bash script halting with ffmpeg?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I have a text file that contains frame numbers line by line and I am using a bash script and ffmpeg to cycle through each line and attempt to print out a thumbnail of each frame.

Each time I run the bash script in my terminal it halts with an error having created the first thumbnail. It seems it is not given the thumbnail a unique name. What am I doing wrong?

My bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source text.txt
while read name
do
ffmpeg -i result.mp4 -vf "setpts=N+1,select='eq(n,$name)'" -vframes 1 frames-$i.jpg
done <text.txt
```

The error:

```
File 'frames-.jpg' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] Not overwriting - exiting
```

Comment: `$i` variable is empty, you never defined it. What do you want it to be?

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: $1 could be a sequential number eg 1,2,3....

Comment: Or $i could be the frame number, I don't mind just now.

Comment: It should be `frames-$name.jpg`

Comment: You haven't observed it yet, but `ffmpeg` will also consume the rest of `text.txt` before the 2nd iteration of the loop starts. Redirect standard input for `ffmpeg` from `/dev/null`.

Comment: I think this might be the problem, can you explain a little further about redirecting standard input for ffmpeg?

Comment: You were right  </dev/null this fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I am guessing you are not needing to `source` the file text.txt in your script. When a file is sourced by `source filename` or `. filename` the lines of code in the file are executed as if they were printed at the command line. As such, I have removed this section of your script.

Second, as noted by others you did not define or update a `$i` variable. A modification as such might work for you:

```
#!/bin/bash

i="0"
while read -r name || [[ -n "${name}" ]]; do  # allows for last line with no newline
    ffmpeg -i result.mp4 -vf "setpts=N+1,select='eq(n,${name})'" -vframes 1 frames-${i}.jpg
    if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
        printf -- 'ffmpeg succeeded - creating frames-%s.jpg for %s\n' "${i}" "${name}"
    else
        printf -- 'ffmpeg failed - was unable to create frames-%s.jpg for %s\n' "${i}" "${name}"
    fi
    let i+="1"
done <text.txt
```

Some additional notes on the script above:

1. It is recommended to use `-r` with `read` to disable interpretation of backslash escapes and line-continuation in the data read. This can keep you from a plague of issues if your input ever has `bash` escapable characters.
2. I added `|| [[ -n "${name}" ]]` to the while condition to allow for the last line in your input file to not have a newline as the last character. Otherwise the last line will be ignored by the standard read process as it requires a newline character at the end of each line.
3. I added a check of the bash builtin variable `$?`. The return value of the previous command is stored in `$?`. `0` indicates success, others indicates error.

---

**EDIT**

If you want to help troubleshoot what ffmpeg is doing, you can try the following modified script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x  # activate bash debugging output

while read -r frame_number || [[ -n "${frame_number}" ]]; do  # allows for last line with no newline
    ffmpeg -i result.mp4 -vf "setpts=N+1,select='eq(n,${frame_number})'" -vframes 1 frames-${frame_number}.jpg
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        printf -- 'ffmpeg succeeded - creating frames-%s.jpg\n' "${frame_number}"
    else
        printf -- 'ffmpeg failed - was unable to create frames-%s.jpg\n' "${frame_number}"
    fi
done <text.txt
```

The edits include:

1. Streamlining the script to use the frame numbers from the text.txt for the jpeg file name.
2. Enabled `bash` debugging by adding `set -x`.

Using the modified script above you should be able to see all the output from `ffmpeg` each time it runs. My mock tests show that all should be functioning correctly per your desired outcomes. Can you test again and report back your findings?

Comment: This is great thanks and for the explanation. But it slightly odd that I only get 22 frames printed when there are 34 in the text file?

Comment: Do all 22 frames have sequential numbers in their names (e.g. frames-0.jpg, frames-1.jpg, frames-2.jpg, frames-3.jpg,...) ? Or are there gaps (e.g. frames-0.jpg, frames-1.jpg, frames-7.jpg, frames-9.jpg...)?

Comment: Yes, the frames are sequential just as you described but strangely the frames I am grabbing don't actually corresspond to the frames in the text file.

Comment: Yes, they are sequential like you describe  ( frames-0.jpg, frames-1.jpg, frames-2.jpg, frames-3.jpg,...)

Comment: Have you tried a sampling of the frames from text.txt by hand to see if any result in an error from ffmpeg? I going to update the script above to check for a non-error output from ffmpeg too.

Comment: Well I did burn in frame numbers onto the video file so I could cross check the frames in the text file with those that get produced into thumb nails. As far as I can be sure the numbers in the text file are what they should be.

Comment: Try deleting all the saved frame-#.jpg files and rerun with the modified script above (which now includes checking for success or failure of the previous ffmpeg command) and report back on what you find.

Comment: Thanks. Seems to still produce 21 frames some are what I expect, some aren't. It seems to not cycle through the frames in order but jumps about which is weird.

Comment: I've just edited the text file so the frame numbers are 100,200,300,400 and 500. The first thumb is printed correctly(frame 100) but the other 4 thumbs are printed with frame 0. (I know it'a frame zero because of burnt in frames). You code reports: ffmpeg succeeded - creating frames-4.jpg for 00

Comment: Run the command manually for one of the failed frames: `ffmpeg -i result.mp4 -vf "setpts=N+1,select='eq(n,300)'" -vframes 1 frames-300.jpg`

Comment: Solved! John Mark Mitchell's bash script worked fine, the problem as spotted by Chepner lay in adding '/dev/null' to ffmpeg script. So it's 'ffmpeg -i result.mp4 -vf  "setpts=N+1,select='eq(n,$name)'" -vframes 1 frames-$i.jpg< /dev/null'

Answer (score 1):

Try defining `$i`:

```
i=0
while read name
do
((i++))
ffmpeg -i result.mp4 -vf "setpts=N+1,select='eq(n,$name)'" -vframes 1 frames-$i.jpg
done <text.txt
```